# VBA Excel creating Outlook email subject and body blank

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I've got an Excel spreadsheet built by someone else that sends an email to a group via a scheduled task, or at least used to. It recently stopped working. I don't have the time to rebuild his whole Rube Goldberg / Wile E. Coyote system at the moment, so I'm trying to fix it.

In one of the excel documents, this code exists

```
Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Sheets("Weight").Range("A2")
On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "eric.lizotte@.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Sheets("Weight").Range("A1")
    .HTMLBody = Convert.ToString(rng)
    .Send
End With
```

whenever I see so many "on error resume next" in something I grit my teeth.

What's happening is that it "works" but the email it sends is blank. In debug I can see that the subject content and body content both exist and have values. I rewrote it to be

```
    OutMail.To = "eric.lizotte@.com"
    OutMail.CC = ""
    OutMail.BCC = ""
    OutMail.Subject = Sheets("Weight").Range("A1")
    OutMail.HTMLBody = Convert.ToString(rng)
    OutMail.Send
```

and threw a debug point on the send, and checked the properties of outmail, and the subject and htmlbody have values. I can't figure out why after the send they are blank.

Comment: Add `.Save` before `.Send`

Comment: Don't rely on the default property of the range - just specify the property you want: `OutMail.Subject = Sheets("Weight").Range("A1").Value` and `OutMail.HTMLBody = rng.Value` or `OutMail.HTMLBody = rng.Text`

Comment: The strange part (to me) is that the exact same code is used in like 50 other spreadsheets, and works fine in those.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie, that worked. I have no idea why for that spreadsheet it craps out on that, considering the subject like ends up as 

Weights - 03/08/17 08:53

and the body is just 

11 = 7.96   13 = 8.02   14 = 8.04   21 = 7.08  23 = 7.49  24 = 7.03 Time = 8:00 AM 

particularly since it works in all the others. Thanks!

Comment: Good stuff- I posted an answer. Feel free to accept if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you are automating another application you probably should not  rely on the default property of the range - just specify the property you want e.g. `Value`:

```
OutMail.Subject = Sheets("Weight").Range("A1").Value 
OutMail.HTMLBody = rng.Value
```

You might also try the `Text` property for the `HTMLBody`:

```
OutMail.HTMLBody = rng.Text
```

You can then be confident that you are assigning a `String` to the mail properties which is what it expects.

Comment: It is mind boggling that for some reason, on that one spreadsheet for that tiny amount of text it needs the .Value where on others that are far more complex it doesn't